# Return data type DataFrame

Tags: go

I have a data frame

```
import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    dataframe "github.com/rocketlaunchr/dataframe-go"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/rocketlaunchr/dataframe-go/imports"
)
```

the outside a main function i have

```
func readFile(fileName string) *Return datatype* {
    covidData, err := os.Open(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    dataFrame, err := imports.LoadFromCSV(ctx, covidData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Read file CSV")
    return (dataFrame)
}
```

I'm needing to return the dataFrame array to the main function, I don't know if this I have to doit with *pointers.

Also in the main func I have to initialize that dataframe.

Edit 1:
i add the return value to dataframe.DataFrame

```golang
func readFile(fileName string) *dataframe.DataFrame {
    covidData, err := os.Open(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    dataFrame, err := imports.LoadFromCSV(ctx, covidData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Read file CSV")
    // fmt.Println("Printing data Frame")
    // Print The whole table
    //fmt.Println(dataFrame)
    fmt.Println("dataFrame", reflect.TypeOf(dataFrame))
    prnNumLst(dataFrame.Names())
    return dataFrame
}
```

seems to work fine thanks to all

Comment: Is it possible you forgot to include the main function code in your post? I ask because you wrote "Also in the main func i have to initialize that dataframe."

Comment: Yes, sorry. i though it was irrelevant. ``` func main() {
 startUpmsg()
 getFileName()
 fmt.Println(fileName)
 downloadFileCheck(URL, fileName)
 readFile(fileName)
} ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**
The return type of `func readFile(fileName string)` should be `*dataframe.DataFrame`.

**Reasoning**
You use the `imports.LoadFromCSV(...)` function to load your CSV file and want to return the resulting data frame. The API documentation of the `github.com/rocketlaunchr/dataframe-go` reveals, that `LoadFromCSV` function a pointer to your dataframe: `*dataframe.DataFrame`.

See documentation here [documentation of LoadFromCSV](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rocketlaunchr/dataframe-go@v0.0.0-20201007021539-67b046771f0b/imports#LoadFromCSV):

> `func LoadFromCSV(ctx context.Context, r io.ReadSeeker, options ...CSVLoadOptions) (*dataframe.DataFrame, error)`\
>
> LoadFromCSV will load data from a csv file.

Comment: thanks man, i also tries that but with this error
```
./main.go:102:2: cannot use dataFrame (type *dataframe.DataFrame) as type dataframe.DataFrame in return argument
```

Comment: Hey, you forgot the star * in front of dataframe.DataFrame.

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept my answers as the solution to your problem. So everyone can see that the problem is solved.